# Xcode - Simulator shows views different from Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-simulator

Auto Layout on Storyboard is working fine, different screens are correctly lay out when I change the view (iPad, iPhone).

[image: iPad - Storyboard Autolayout]

[image: iPhone Storyboard Autolayout]

However, when using Simulator, the result is different than on Storyboard (note the green arrows).

[image: Simulator layout is NOT the same as the Storyboard Auto Layout]

Comment: is your app Universal?

Comment: Nope, SOLVED! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button with the text **1X** in the lower-right corner indicates that your app is not scaled properly and is **iPhone only**.

Under **Project settings/Targets/[your target]/General/Deployment Info/Devices**, check **Universal** instead of iPhone.

[image: Project settings/Targets]
[image: Deployment info settings]